# Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 when sanitizing WordPress export content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, nokogiri, sanitize

I'm writing a script to import WordPress content to my Rails application. I need to remove all images from the body of the post. When viewing the post I get an `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` error.

```
require 'action_view'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'sanitize'

namespace :wordpress do
  desc 'Import Worpress Posts'
  task import_posts: :environment do |_, _args|
    IMAGE_REGEX = /"([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))"/i
    user_id = User.first[:id]
    Blogit::Post.destroy_all
    File.open('lib/post.xml') do |file|
      items = Nokogiri::XML(file).xpath('//channel//item')
      items.each do |item|
        body = Sanitize.fragment(item.at_xpath('content:encoded').text).force_encoding('UTF-8')
               .encode('UTF-16', invalid: :replace, replace: '')
               .encode('UTF-8')

        begin
          post = Blogit::Post.create(
            title: item.at_xpath('wp:post_name').text.strip,
            body: body,
            blogger_id: user_id,
            bootsy_image_gallery: Bootsy::ImageGallery.create
          )
          images = item.at_xpath('content:encoded').text.scan(IMAGE_REGEX).map(&:first)
          post.save(validate: false)
          # post.update_column(:created_at, item.at_xpath('wp:post_date_gmt').text + ' +0000')
          # if images.any?
          #   images.each do |image|
          #     post.remote_feature_image_url = image.first
          #     post.bootsy_image_gallery.images << Bootsy::Image.create(remote_image_file_url: image.first)
          #   end
          #   post.save
          # end
        rescue StandardError => e
          puts "#{e}"
          next
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error is thrown here:

```
= content_tag(:article, id: "blog_post_#{post.id}", class: "blog_post") do
```

This is _post.html.slim:

```
= content_tag(:article, id: "blog_post_#{post.id}", class: "blog_post") do
  / Render the header for this blog post
  = render "blogit/posts/post_head", post: post

  / Render Post Image Slider
  / = render "blogit/posts/slider", images: post.bootsy_image_gallery.images if post.bootsy_image_gallery.images.any?

  / Render the body of this blog post (as Markdown)
  = render "blogit/posts/post_body", post: post

  / Render admin links to edit/delete this post
  = render "blogit/posts/post_links", post: post

  / Render info about the person who wrote this post
  = render "blogit/posts/blogger_information", post: post

  = render 'elements/tags', post: post

  / Render the no. of comments
  - if defined?(show_comments_count) and show_comments_count
    = render "blogit/posts/comments_count", post: post
```

Comment: You don't say what version of Ruby and Rails you're on. Current Rubies, v2.0+ default to UTF-8. You also don't show us a minimal sample of the incoming XML,  that would trigger the problem. Without that you're making us guess and imagine, neither of which do anyone any good.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the illegal bytes by simply calling `String#scrub`, or `#scrub!`, which exists in MRI 2.1.0 and subsequent.

```
body = Sanitize.fragment(item.at_xpath('content:encoded').text).force_encoding('UTF-8').scrub
```

There is no need for the

```
.encode('UTF-16', invalid: :replace, replace: '').encode('UTF-8')
```

lines. You're trying to do what `scrub` actually does, just use `scrub`.

This should keep you from getting an exception, depending on where the exception is actually being raised. You didn't give us a line number for the exception. You may need to `scrub` other data pieces you are getting from the XML, such as the title and images too.

It should keep you from getting an exception by replacing all invalid bytes with the Unicode replacement character (`�`). but whether it's the RIGHT solution or not depends on what's going on with your source text, why it's got invalid UTF-8 bytes in it.  If you've just got a few `�` here and there, maybe it just had some bad bytes. If you find all or many of your accented or non-ASCII chars are replaced with `�`, then you're going to have to figure out why the encoding is being corrupted and fix it properly.

Comment: Thats not helping either. `body = Sanitize.fragment(item.at_xpath('content:encoded').text).scrub` or `body = Sanitize.fragment(item.at_xpath('content:encoded').text.scrub)`

Comment: Okay, you need to tell us exactly what line is raising the exception.

Comment: The exception comes with a stack trace showing which lines of your code and gem code you used are involved at the moment the exception is raised. That's what you need to look at to begin debugging it, you first need to know exactly what line causes it.

Answer (score 1):

You say your error is thrown at:

```
= content_tag(:article, id: "blog_post_#{post.id}", class: "blog_post") do
```

However, this line doesn't even appear in the source code you pasted in above that.

If the error is really being thrown by that line, then it means you have illegal bytes in `post.id`. Which seems pretty unlikely. But if you really did, you could resolve the 'illegal byte' exception by `scrub`ing the post.id....

```
content_tag(:article, id: "blog_post_#{post.id.scrub}", class: "blog_post") do
```

But that would probably just cause further problems down the line. If this is really what's going on, you'd have to figure out why there's an illegal byte in your post.id in the first place, and fix the underlying problem.

However, I am skeptical, I do not think you are accurately diagnosing which line is raising the exception.

Good luck.